# my debugger is not working correctly in react native

Tags: react-native, node-modules, npx

I want to debug my code in react native but whenever I press "open debbuger" nothing changes

my debug url: http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/

and my status

Status: Waiting, press ⌘R in simulator to reload and connect.

Every time I press the "open debugger" button, I get the text in my terminal like this:

**info Opening flipper://null/Hermesdebuggerrn?device=React%20Native...**

and I also use this link "chrome://inspect/#devices" to use "Hermes React Native" but when I debug it, it doesn't debug there or it doesn't showed when I type something in the console

**npx react-native info output**

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
  OS: macOS 13.0.1
  CPU: (8) x64 Apple M1
  Memory: 42.82 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: 5.8.1
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 20.5.0
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.5.0/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.19
    path: /usr/local/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 9.8.1
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.5.0/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2023.08.14.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.12.1
    path: /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 22.4
      - iOS 16.4
      - macOS 13.3
      - tvOS 16.4
      - watchOS 9.4
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.10671973
  Xcode:
    version: 14.3.1/14E300c
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 17.0.8
    path: /usr/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 2.6.10
    path: /usr/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.72.4
    wanted: 0.72.4
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because Hermes is enabled by default. You can disable the Hermes or you can use **flipper debugger** which is developed by meta [Flipper download link](https://fbflipper.com/)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work when I disabled hermes, then I used Reactotron and Flipper, but they didn't stop at the line of code I debugged, so it didn't work.